# Why does execution time equal to 0ms?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get an execution time, but it returns 0ms. Where might be the problem? Here is the query:

```
SET STATISTICS TIME ON

SELECT 
    s.Credit_book_number AS Студ_номер,
    (s.Last_name + s.First_name + s.Patronymic) AS ФИО,
    AVG(Grade) AS Средняя_оценка 
FROM 
    GradeList g 
JOIN 
    Student s ON s.Credit_book_number = g.Credit_book_number 
GROUP BY 
    s.Credit_book_number, 
    (s.Last_name + s.First_name + s.Patronymic) 
HAVING
    AVG(Grade) >= 8 

SET STATISTICS TIME OFF
```

Comment: Its so quick it can't measure it?

Comment: @DaleK and what exactly can make a query slower?

Comment: Everything? Hardware, rows in table, indexes, statistics, size of data, how busy server is...

Comment: How about after you run `dbcc dropcleanbuffers; dbcc freeproccache` ?

Comment: @Stu the same 0 ms..

Comment: Check the properties tab of SSMS also. It's probably measuing in microseconds and being rounded down, stats IO does not have particularly reliable values. Try using something like SP_Blitzcache.

Comment: In a separate SSMS window, I suggest a) make a #temporary table with appropriate fields, b) `SET NOCOUNT ON;`  c) change the query to an `INSERT` with the select statement from above, then d) try the query followed by `GO 100` or even `GO 1000` (but first test with `GO 2` or `GO 3` or so). GO with a number runs the command that many times. While doing an INSERT will make it take a bit of time, it won't be massive. But if running the process a thousand times takes a few seconds, you know it runs pretty quickly. Note though that for a query that quick, exact times will be tough to calculate.